# NestJs - How to get url of handler?

Tags: nestjs

I want to redirect user to another url in my server, but I do not want to hardcode url like `res.redirect('/hello_world')`. Instead I want to just specify handler's url of specified controller like `res.redirect(HelloWorldController.handlerName.url)` where HelloWorldContoller is

```
@Controller()
export class HelloWorldController {
    @Get('hello_world')
    handlerName(): string {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, you can use **Reflect** to get metadata like this:

```
import { PATH_METADATA } from '@nestjs/common/constants';

@Controller('api')
export class ApiController {
  @Get('hello')
  root() {
    let routePath = Reflect.getMetadata(PATH_METADATA, StaticController);
    routePath += '/' + Reflect.getMetadata(PATH_METADATA, StaticController.prototype.serveStatic);
    console.log(routePath); will return `api/hello`
    return {
      message: 'Hello World!',
    };
  }
}
```

1. We get api metadata
2. Then it's methods

> Why it returns api/hello if I need a path not of self url, but other
>   controller's url?

Here `StaticController` is used as an example, You can import any other controllers and pass it to `Reflect.getMetadata(PATH_METADATA, AnyOtherController);`

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but there are some misunderstandings: 1st - What is a PATH_METADATA? and 2nd - Why it returns `api/hello` if I need a path not of self url, but other controller's url?

Comment: Ok. I understood. Instead of PATH_METADATA, we write 'path'. And we get url of specified controller's path and method's path. However, I thought that there will be NestJS's helper function that returns full path, instead of creating it by yourself. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NursultanZarlyk, you can also look at `NestJS` realization in source code: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/91c879d9225d8c4ef125ca7f5e8ee555e9a0b872/packages/core/router/router-explorer.ts#L82-L92. There are some helper functions